# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #5](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/5) on SharePoint has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Trevor Seward]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/5) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4807333319278592).

Comment: @ Trevor So pleased to see you in the moderator list, and Congratulations on your new well-deserved role. Good Luck ♥ @Slat thank you for all your support ♥

Comment: Many congratulations @Trevor Seward!! Thank you Slate for all the support during election.

Comment: Congratulations, @Trevor!